# Issu using startMATLAB in C++ with "MatlabEngine.hpp" in r2017b

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio-2017, matlab-engine

In its new version 2017b, Matlab has released a new MATLAB Engine API for C++: https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-cpp-programs.html

When I try to use this API, (only to start Matlab at the beginning !!), I have an issue using :

```
std::unique_ptr<MATLABEngine> matlabPtr = startMATLAB();
```

The compilation is ok, but at the execution :

[image]

Here is the call stack:

> matlab::engine::initSession --> matlab::engine::startMATLAB -->
>   matlab::engine::startMATLABAsync --> engine_create_session

Now, I use a different way to do my job, but I don't want to let an issue without a solution. Can someone spot the problem with this API?

My configuration :

- Matlab 2017b
- Visual Studio 2017
- Windows 10

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem and no idea how to solve, even more, my program was working perfectly and from one day to another this show up. Please let me know if you solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @JP Cordova,
A magic trick append. Since Matlab 2018a, in Released mode, it's now working. I still face the issue with Debug mode and I have no clue why.

Comment: Maybe I can help, I unchecked some exceptions from Exceptions Settings, and that did the trick for me, seems like Matlab rise exceptions not only when an error happens and visual studio catch them as errors anyway. To see if this is correct, press continue when the 'exception error' shows up, and if you don't find any problem (memory leaks, etc...) is because of that. To avoid catching those exceptions, press CTR-ALT-E in visual studio (or Debug->Windows->Exception Settings) and test the options.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few days back, I had the same issue: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50883678/unable-to-interface-my-c-application-with-matlab)

So, I had raised a ticket in MATLAB for technical support. And they suggested to build the project in the following manner which works for me:

1. Create a project and add the source file.
2. Go to the project properties, and do the following changes(***Make sure to change the architecture to X64***):
3. Under **C/C++ General**, add the following directory to the field
   **ADDITIONAL INCLUDE DIRECTORIES:** *C:\Program Files\MATLAB\\extern\include*
4. Under **C/C++ Precompiled Headers**, select *"Not Using Precompiled
   Headers"*.
5. Under **Linker General**, add the directory to the field **ADDITIONAL
   LIBRARY DIRECTORIES:** *C:\Program
   Files\MATLAB\\extern\lib\win64\microsoft*
6. e. Under **Configuration Properties ->Debugging** Add the following 2
   Target paths in the Environment: *PATH=C:\Program
   Files\MATLAB\\bin\win64;
    PATH=C:\Program
   Files\MATLAB\\extern\bin\win64;*
7. Under **Linker Input**, add the following names to the field marked **ADDITIONAL DEPENDENCIES:**
   *libmat.lib

   libMatlabEngine.lib

   libMatlabDataArray.lib*
8. Make sure that the following directory is in the **Windows system
   environment PATH**: 
   *C:\Program Files\MATLAB\\bin\win64;

   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\\extern\bin\win64*
9. Now, build the project and run your application.

Answer (score 1):

Like in the comment, I solved the issue by upgrading Matlab from R2017b to R2018b!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple. After setting include and library folders, DONOT copy ANY dll files to your own build folder. Then, it will work.