# unable to interface my c++ application with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, c++11

I have written a program in c++11. My intention is to use MATLAB environment for plotting.

So, I followed these two links to have some idea:[MATLAB_Build C++ Engine programs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/build-c-engine-programs.html) and [c++ start MATLAB session](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/start-and-connect-to-a-matlab-sessions-from-c.html). (*There must be other ways to interface MATLAB and c++. But I want to know where is my fault before trying other ones*)

As those above links have suggested I built my project accordingly using **visual studio '17**. The initial errors that I found was, my application could not locate the following .dll files **libMatlabEngine.dll, libMatlabdataArray.lib**.

So, I moved my .dlls to the executable location as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953843/why-cant-visual-studio-find-my-dll). But after then my code is throwing the following ***error:  0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000.***

Below is the piece of code that I'm trying. I guess it's the startMATLAB() which is returning a NULL pointer and the code is failing for that. But I can't figure out what's the reason.

Appreciate your help.

```
//Start the MATLAB engine
using namespace matlab::engine;
using namespace matlab::data;

unique_ptr<MATLABEngine> matlabptr = startMATLAB();

//Cretae a matlab array factory
ArrayFactory factory;
auto inputArray = factory.createArray({ 1, 6 }, cppData.cbegin(), cppData.cend());
auto time_array = factory.createArray({ 1, 6 }, time.cbegin(), time.cend());

matlabptr->setVariable(convertUTF8StringToUTF16String("data"), move(inputArray));
matlabptr->setVariable(convertUTF8StringToUTF16String("time"), move(time_array));

matlabptr->eval(convertUTF8StringToUTF16String("plot(time, data)"));
```

Comment: This issue has been already discussed here. But it seems like no one has found a proper solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693078/issu-using-startmatlab-in-c-with-matlabengine-hpp-in-r2017b?rq=1